# Windows 10 stuck on startup screen

Tags: windows-10, boot, start-screen

After I shut down my Acer (Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.15]), the laptop suddenly doesn't boot anymore. I basically just try to run different commands in the hope that this fixes W10. After I force shutdown from the loading screen, the next boot gives "Your PC did not start correctly."

- Startup Repair gives "Startup Repair couldn't repair your PC".
- The CMD directory is "X:\Windows\system32", and cd C: only prints "C:\".
- bootrec /fixrec prints "Access is denied."
- bootrec /scanos also prints "Total identified Windows installations: 0".
- sfc /scannow also prints "[...] Verification 100% complete. Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation."
- chkdsk /f also prints "Cannot lock current drive."
- chkdsk C: /f /r /x also prints "Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems. No further action is required. [...] Failed to transfer logged messages to the event log with status 50."

**How can I solve this problem?** [And if this requires a kind of reset, what options will delete what files on my system? I have documents on the computer not backed up.]

**EDIT:** After I had my other laptop connected to the internet for a while, the same problem happened and I can't boot that W10 either.

Comment: There a reason your system is more then 6 months out of date?

Comment: I didn't know my version of Windows was not up to date. Must be a bug with Windows Update.

Comment: could you boot into safe Mode? This is the recovery methods provided by Microsoft:https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options